# Broken Wordpress Deployment on GCP after Copute Engine Name Change

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-deployment-manager

I have a Wordpress instance on GCP's compute engine, deployed via the deployment manager.

I recenetly renamed the underlying compute engine instance. Nothing else has changed including the IP address. I can still access the page just fine through the domain or IP address, but the deployment manager can no longer read the info.

I get a "Failed to evaluate expression" error. How can I correct the connection?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried restarting your instance?

Comment: Yea I did. And I even reverted the name, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I do have here a non-Google [documentation](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/wordpress-error-establishing-database-connection) on steps that you can follow on fixing the connection to your database.

For the issue with the site URL and Admi URL, attaching as well non-Google [documentation](https://wp-me.com/cant-access-wordpress-after-changing-site-url/) to give you guide.